# Comment conjuguer un verbe qui suit une préposition

Tags: prépositions, conjugaison, correspondance

Par example:

> De ces cendres [s'élever] un phénix.

Conjugue-le comme « s'élèvent » (correspondant avec « ces cendres ») ou s'élève (correspondant avec « un phénix »).

(Je crois que le sujet est « un phénix » donc il faut le conjuguer comme « s'élève ».)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu as raison : le phénix est toujours le sujet. Pour l'identifier il ne faut que se demander : Qui est-ce qui fait l'action ? Qui est-ce qui s'élève ? C'est le phénix, pas les cendres.

Alors, on conjugue pour un sujet singulier : s'élève.

N'oublie pas que tu peux vérifier ce type de conjugaison en essayant un autre verbe dont les formes du pluriel se distinguent à l'oreille :

> De ces cendres **vient** / viennent un phénix.

Comment: Quelqu'un qui se pose cette question se demandera sans doute également s'il convient d'utiliser vient ou viennent... je pense que le meilleur conseil qu'on puisse donner est effectivement d'identifier le sujet.

Comment: @LaurentS. Cela est vrai pour les apprenants, mais je trouve que chez les locuteur natifs on a des difficultés avec ce qui s'écrit différement mais se prononce de la même façon : j'ai appris cette méthode à quelques-uns qui l'ont trouvée utile. (J'ai pris l'OP pour une locutrice native.) Mais tu as raison, il est important pour tout le monde de pouvoir identifier le sujet.

Comment: Moi, je régarde la structure  ou structure (poétique) pour voir si l'on peut la transposer: De ces cendres [s'élever] un phénix.= Un phénix s'élève de ces cendres. Cad, cela revient à la même chose que "trouver le sujet" mais c'est, disons, *in extenso*.